# Math.pow and Math.sqrt work differently for large values?

Tags: java, math

I'm using Heron's formula to find the area of a triangle. Given sides `a`, `b`, and `c`, `A = √(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))` where s is the semiperimeter `(a+b+c)/2`. This formula should work perfectly, but I noticed that Math.pow() and Math.sqrt() give different results. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?
I wrote two methods that find the area and determine if it is an integer.

In this first method, I take the square roots and then multiply them:

```
public static boolean isAreaIntegral(long a, long b, long c)
{
  double s = (a+b+c)/2.0;
  double area = Math.sqrt(s)*Math.sqrt(s-a)*Math.sqrt(s-b)*Math.sqrt(s-c);
  return area%1.0==0.0 && area > 0.0;
}
```

In this second method, I find the product and then take the square root:

```
public static boolean isAreaIntegral(long a, long b, long c)
{
  double s = (a+b+c)/2.0;
  double area = Math.pow(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c),0.5);
  return area%1.0==0.0 && area > 0.0;
}
```

Can anyone explain why these two methods that are mathematically equivalent give different Values? I'm working on [Project Euler Problem 94](https://projecteuler.net/problem=94). My answer comes out to `999990060` the first way and `996784416` the second way. (I know that both answers are very far off the actual)

Comment: What are the values of `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Comment: Have you actually compared `sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)` vs. `pow(...,0.5)` ? In any case, isn't there a much simpler formula to calculate the area in the form `2*(A/2*B)` ...

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly vote for "rounding issues", as you multiply the results of multiple method call in the first method (where every method result gets rounded) compared to the single method call in the second method, where you round only once.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the answers is larger than I'd expect. Or maybe it isn't. It's late and my mathematical mind crashed a while ago.

I think your issue is with rounding. When you multiply a load of roots together, your answer falls further from the true value.

The second method will be more accurate.
Though, not necessarily as accurate as Euler is asking for.
A calculator is a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are problematic. You should in general be *very* careful when comparing floating point values (that is, also *double* precision floating point values). Particularly, comparing the *result of a computation* with `==` or `!=` is nearly always questionable (and quite often it is just *wrong*). Comparing two floating point values for "equality" should be done with a method like

```
private static boolean isEqual(double x, double y)
{
  double epsilon = 1e-8;
  return Math.abs(x - y) <= epsilon * Math.abs(x);
  // see Knuth section 4.2.2 pages 217-218
}
```

In this case, the floating-point remainder operator will also not have the desired result. Consider the following, classic example

```
public class PrecisionAgain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double d = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            d += 0.1;
        }
        System.out.println(d);

        double r = d%1.0;
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2.0000000000000004
4.440892098500626E-16
```

In your case, in order to rule out these rounding errors, the return statement could probably (!) something simple like

```
return (area - Math.round(area) < 1e8);
```

But in other situations, you should definitely read more about floating point operations. (The site http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html is often recommended, but might be a tough one to start with...)

This still does not really answer your actual question: WHY are the results different? In doubt, the answer is this simple: Because they make different errors (but they both make errors - that's in fact more important here!)